# Why does my web scraper only work half the time?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal is to get the product name and price of all Amazon pages detected in any website that I feed to my program.

My input is a text file containing five websites. In each of these websites, a total of five to fifteen amazon links are to be found.

My code is this:

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict
from time import sleep
import time
from lxml import html
import json
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, HTTPError, URLError

def isdead(url):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/20.0.1 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
    headers = { 'User-Agent':user_agent }
    req = Request(url, headers = headers)
    sleep(10)
    try:
        page_open = urlopen(req)
    except HTTPError, e:
        return e.code #404 if link is broken
    except URLError, e:
        return e.reason
    else:
        return False

def check(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

    doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
    XPATH_AVAILABILITY = '//div[@id ="availability"]//text()'
    RAw_AVAILABILITY = doc.xpath(XPATH_AVAILABILITY)
    AVAILABILITY = ''.join(RAw_AVAILABILITY).strip()
    #re.... is a list. if empty, available. if not, unavailable.
    #return re.findall(r'Available from',AVAILABILITY[:30], re.IGNORECASE)

    if len(re.findall(r'unavailable',AVAILABILITY[:30],re.IGNORECASE)) == 1:
        return "unavailable"
    else:
        return "available"


file_name = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
filepath = "%s"%(file_name)

with open(filepath) as f:
    listoflinks = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

all_links = []
for i in listoflinks:
    htmls = req.get(i)
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(htmls)
    amazon_links = doc.getElements('a')
    amazon_links = amazon_links.containsOr(['https://www.amazon.com/','https://amzn.to/'],attr='href')
    for a in amazon_links:
        if a.href not in all_links:
            all_links.append(a.href)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

all_links = [x for x in all_links if "amazon.com/gp/prime" not in x]
all_links = [y for y in all_links if "amazon.com/product-reviews" not in y]
for i in all_links:
    print "LINK:"
    print i
    response = requests.get(i, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="lxml")

    if isdead(i) == 404:
        print "DOES NOT EXIST"
        print "/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/"
        pass
    else:
        title = soup.select("#productTitle")[0].get_text().strip()
        if check(i) == "unavailable":
            price = "UNAVAILABLE"
        else:
            if (len(soup.select("#priceblock_ourprice")) == 0) and (len(soup.select("#priceblock_saleprice")) == 0):
                price = soup.select("#a-offscreen")
            elif len(soup.select("#priceblock_ourprice")) == 0:
                price = soup.select("#priceblock_saleprice")
            else:
                price = soup.select("#priceblock_ourprice")

        print "TITLE:%s"%(title)
        print "PRICE:%s"%(price)
        print "/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/"

print "..............................................."
print "FINALLY..."
print "# OF LINKS RETRIEVED:"
print len(all_links)
```

Whenever it works fine, the output looks something like this (please don't judge the PRICE output, I have spent so much time trying to fix that but nothing works because I can't turn it into a string and get_text() doesn't work. This project is just for personal use so it's not that important, but if you have suggestions, I'm very receptive to those.):

```
LINK:
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B007Y6LLTM/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=ll1&tag=lunagtkf1-20&linkId=ee8c5299508af57c815ea6577ede4244
TITLE:Moen 7594ESRS Arbor Motionsense Two-Sensor Touchless One-Handle Pulldown Kitchen Faucet Featuring Power Clean, Spot Resist Stainless
PRICE:[<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString" id="priceblock_ourprice">$359.99</span>]
/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/
```

... and so on.
The error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "name.py", line 75, in <module>
title = soup.select("#productTitle")[0].get_text().strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It's so weird because there's a text file that's fed so many times and sometimes, all sites are scraped well, but sometimes, the error appears at the 10th Amazon product, sometimes, the error appears at the 1st product...

I'm suspecting it's a bot detection problem, but I have a header. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too messy. I've organized it for you, please check out if it works.

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
import requests

file_name = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
filepath = "%s"%(file_name)

with open(filepath) as f:
    listoflinks = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

all_links = []
for i in listoflinks:
    htmls = req.get(i)
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(htmls)
    amazon_links = doc.getElements('a')
    amazon_links = amazon_links.containsOr(['https://www.amazon.com/','https://amzn.to/'],attr='href')
    amazon_links = amazon_links.notContains(['amazon.com/gp/prime','amazon.com/product-reviews'],attr='href')
    for a in amazon_links:
        if a.href not in all_links:
            all_links.append(a.href)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

for i in all_links:
    print "LINK:"
    print i
    response = requests.get(i, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 404:
        print "DOES NOT EXIST"
        print "/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/"
        pass
    else:
        html = response.text
        doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
        title = doc.getElementByID("productTitle").text
        if doc.getElementByID('availability') and doc.getElementByID('availability').text.find('unavailable')>0:
            price = "UNAVAILABLE"
        else:
            if doc.getElementByID("priceblock_ourprice"):
                price = doc.getElementByID("priceblock_ourprice").text
            elif doc.getElementByID("priceblock_saleprice"):
                price = doc.getElementByID("priceblock_saleprice").text
            else:
                price = doc.getElementByID("a-offscreen").text

        print "TITLE:%s"%(title)
        print "PRICE:%s"%(price)
        print "/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/"

print "..............................................."
print "FINALLY..."
print "# OF LINKS RETRIEVED:"
print len(all_links)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more:) and give you an example of using the framework.
Here are more examples of simplified_scrapy [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo)

If you need any help, please let me know.

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import Spider, SimplifiedDoc
class MySpider(Spider):
  name = 'amazon-product'
  # allowed_domains = ['example.com']
  start_urls = []
  refresh_urls = True # For debug. If efresh_urls = True, start_urls will be crawled again.

  filepath='' # Your file path
  if filepath:
    with open(filepath) as f:
      start_urls = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

  def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
    amazon_links=None
    data = None
    if url['url'].find('https://www.amazon.com')>=0 or url['url'].find('https://amzn.to')>=0:
      title = doc.getElementByID("productTitle").text
      if doc.getElementByID('availability') and doc.getElementByID('availability').text.find('unavailable')>0:
        price = "UNAVAILABLE"
      else:
        if doc.getElementByID("priceblock_ourprice"):
          price = doc.getElementByID("priceblock_ourprice").text
        elif doc.getElementByID("priceblock_saleprice"):
          price = doc.getElementByID("priceblock_saleprice").text
        else:
          price = doc.getElementByID("a-offscreen").text

      data = [{"title":title,'price':price}] # Get target data
      print "TITLE:%s"%(title)
      print "PRICE:%s"%(price)
      print "/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/"
    else:
      amazon_links = doc.getElements('a')
      amazon_links = amazon_links.containsOr(['https://www.amazon.com/','https://amzn.to/'],attr='href')
      amazon_links = amazon_links.notContains(['amazon.com/gp/prime','amazon.com/product-reviews'],attr='href')
    return {"Urls": amazon_links, "Data": data} # Return data to framework

from simplified_scrapy.simplified_main import SimplifiedMain
SimplifiedMain.startThread(MySpider()) # Start crawling
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this and this kept printing on my terminal: https://imgur.com/4TYa1zo

Comment: This is the normal system log, indicating that the system is running well. Have you assigned a value to filepath? If the data is collected, it will be automatically saved in the "data" folder under the root directory.

Comment: Yes, I already assigned a file path. Ok, I'll check out the directory. Thanks!